# ESO - Morrowind - Is Seyda Neen quest chain incomplete?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I have a question about the slavers quest chain (Morrowind, first city - minor spoilers ahead)...

I started the quest (can't remember the quest name... is exactly at entrance - if you started with the tutorial can't miss it, if you came with an older char is right near the skyshard in Seyda Neen). Talked with the guard on the lighthouse, talk with Cherish-Water etc. All went normal until I freed the slaves. Then you come back and you are suppose to uncover the governor as the bad guy.

You enter the house and you find a beat up guard and the dark elf lady that started the quest. The guard says the governor attacked him then the dark elf lady (can't remember the name) says something like: "He is trying to escape justice! After him!" and runs out. Then I exist the house and... that's it. Nothing else, the zone appears as completed on map. I expected to follow the guy or something. Also there is a zone on the isle where I rescued slaves that was inaccessible (I was expecting it will become open later in quest chain).

My question is: Did I miss anything? Have I encountered a bug where a npc did not spawn or something? Or this is normal and I will continue later (maybe another quest from another city - Balmora comes into mind :)) continues this)? Or that's just it and the guy runs? Seems... incomplete to me. I don't mind open endings but since Morrowind was barely released I'm afraid is a bug and don't wanna miss... things.

Maybe some1 can shed some light for me?

Thank you and have fun all.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, doesn't the Morrowind DLC for ESO not come out until June 6th?

Comment: @n_palum They finished earlier so is out already - although the official release date is still June 6th :). That's kind of rare actually.

Comment: and it was released? Are you sure? "We're excited to announce that The Elder Scrolls Online: Morrowind will be live on all platforms and megaservers at 5:00am EDT on June 6!" - http://www.elderscrollsonline.com/en-us/news/post/2017/05/23/launch-details-for-the-elder-scrolls-online-morrowind

Comment: Pretty sure since there are a few thousands ppl in the area. Let me find a link.

Comment: @n_palum Here you go: http://www.elderscrollsonline.com/en-us/news/post/2017/05/10/eso-morrowind-early-access-details (is just for pc & mac since May 22)

Comment: Oh okay, so it's early access for some. Good to know